# Implementing Google Search in Search Bar

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad, uisearchbar

How can I implement Google Search using the Search Bar in iPad/iPhone App ? Any tutorial will be very helpful.

Regards !!

Comment: I don't mean to sound nitpicky, but what do you mean you want to implement Google search? Do you mean you want to include the search capability in your application or you want to create/build your own search algorithm? If you want to add search to your app, there are tons of API's out there and i would start by looking at what KMan has suggested. If that is not the case, then you have alot of reading to catch up on :-)

Comment: I don't want to create/build my own search algorithm (at least for now). I want the search capability in my application. I am not getting exactly from where to start. So can I have any step by step tutorial ?(I am a newbie to iOS App dev.)

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why the down vote? I was just trying to understand what he wanted to do.

Comment: Have you find out the way for it,i am facing the same problem and not able to find any tutorial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checkout:

- [How To Use Google APIs with iPhone SDK](http://johntwang.com/blog/2009/06/08/how-to-use-google-apis-with-iphone-sdk/)